# How to store generic four bytes that can initialize to either integer or float

Tags: c, byte

I'm trying to write a list of settings that get memcpy'ed in place.  This will be a very large list (100+ items) that a developer is going to spend time tuning.  I want to be able to initialize any of these to either a 4 byte floating point or 4 byte integer.

What I want:

```
{.settingName="setting 1", .value=0.5f},
{.settingName="setting 2", .value=0.5f},
{.settingName="setting 3", .value=300},
```

Because a dev is going to spend time tuning these values, I can't just initialize 0x3f000000 in place of 0.5f

I also can't store this as a float:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

uint8_t data[sizeof(float)];

int main(){
    float f = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    memcpy(data, &f, sizeof(f));
    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(data); i++){
        printf("%x ", data[sizeof(data)-1-i]);
    }
    uint32_t integer = (uint32_t) f;
    printf("\n%x ", integer);
}
```

because this outputs:
4f 80 0 0
integer:0

Is this possible in C?

Comment: The important question is *why do you want this*? The answer to this question would normally indicate that you are taking an incorrect approach to solving the underlying problem.

Comment: Why don't use use a union, then just do `{ .settingName = "setting 1", .value_f = 0.5f }, { .settingName = "setting 3", .value_i = 300 }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `union`, but then you need a method to tell whether the value is an integer or a float.

```
union number {
    int i;
    float f;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a struct containing a union and a flag indicating which member of the union is active

```
typedef struct {
    typedef union {
        int ival;
        float fval;
    } data;
    enum {
        INT,
        FLOAT;
    } which;
} dataContainer;
```

Comment: Interesting, would you mind adding an example? (Main)